# Can't size instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

I was wondering why some assembly instructions can be inferred, but others cannot. For example, in the following program I have:

```
.globl main
main:
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp, %rbp
    mov $8, -8(%rbp)
    mov -8(%rbp), %rax
    pop %rbp
    ret
```

I get the following error:

> stack.s:5: Error: no instruction mnemonic suffix given and no register operands; can't size instruction

However, if I change: the 5th line to:

```
movq $8, -8(%rbp)
```

It runs without error. How can all the other operations infer the size, but that particular instruction cannot?

Comment: Because `mov $8, -8(%rbp)` says move the value 8 to a memory location, but how big a value is 8. Is it a byte with 8, a word with 0x08 a long with 0x08 in it a quadword with 0x08? That is why you have to specify the size because the size can't be determine by either operand. Int other cases one of the operands is a register and a register has a known width. As an example RAX is 64-bit register EAX is a 32-bit register, AX is a 16-bit register, AL/AH are 8 bit registers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hint is in the message: "no register operands".

All the other instructions have a register as an operand, and the assembler knows how large the registers are.  So for instance, `mov %rax, -8(%rbp)` must be a quadword move (8 bytes) because `%rax` is a 64-bit register.  Likewise, `mov %eax, -8(%rbp)`, `mov %ax, -8(%rbp)`, and `mov %al, -8(%rbp)` will be longword / word / byte moves (4 / 2 / 1 bytes).  As such, the size suffix is optional for those instructions.

But the immediate constant `$8` has no inherent size, so the assembler has no way to know what size you wanted unless you tell it.

Comment: Note that GAS unfortunately *doesn't* error on `add $8, -8(%rbp)`.  (Binutils 2.34) Instead it picks dword operand-size as a default.  I think I read that historically AT&T's unix assembler did that, but that's a terrible reason for keeping this dangerous behaviour.  Not to mention inconsistent, both mov and add are available in all sizes from byte to qword.  Maybe someone should report a bug, it might be unintentional behaviour.

Comment: Remembered where I saw that: [in the GAS manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMnemonics.html).  *Note that this is incompatible with the AT&T Unix assembler which assumes that a missing mnemonic suffix implies long operand size. (This incompatibility does not affect compiler output since compilers always explicitly specify the mnemonic suffix.)*  So I think that is a bug, not intentional.